# specifying css if surrounded by a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass

im trying to do the following in my rails application:

lets say i have a class .foo

```
 .foo{ color:red;}
```

and i have another class .bar

```
.bar{ color:green;}
```

i want the color off the foo elements to be changed to say blue, ONLY when **surrounded by a bar class**

example :  here i want "blah blah" to be blue

```
<div class = "bar" >
  <div class = "foo" >
  blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

how do i do it? without using LESS or anything like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write like this:

```
.bar .foo{
color:blue
}
```

& for more specific write like this:

```
.bar > .foo{
    color:blue
    }
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/DEmk7/1/

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning the `>` combinator as well, since 'surrounds' sort of suggests that it might be used only for an immediate child.

Answer (score 1):

According to this example:

```
<div class = "bar" >
  <div class = "foo" >
  blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

You can give your div with class foo an other class too.

```
<div class = "bar" >
  <div class = "foo blue" >
  blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

In your css you write the following:

```
.foo{ color:red;}
.bar{ color:green;}
.blue{color:blue !important;}
```

Comment: !important should generally be avoided in favour of using the natural css cascade, a useful article:http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: I don't think it's a problem to use it. It works fine, so for me there is no problem.

Comment: Indeed Alex after reading that article I was immediately convinced so I'm trying to spread the word.

Comment: Was just looking for a small problem on my website. After 1 hour of thinking and looking for a correct answer, I finally fixed it with ...
!important; :D Sorry, just wanted to mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You can seperate css selectors by a space to specify nesting. 
e.g.

```
.bar .foo
{
    color:blue;
}
```

Notably in this format, it will match both:

```
<div class = "bar" >
  <div class = "foo" >
  blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class = "bar" >
  <div class = "yay" >
    <div class="foo">
      blah blah
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using the ">" child selector will allow you to target only direct children, meaning the one with yay won't be matched.